# Prediction IO - Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext

Tags: java, apache-spark, predictionio

I installed PredictionIO 0.9.6 everything is running. After that I install PredictionIO-Churn-Prediction-H2O-Sparkling-Water engine. The engine is running too. I can see here `https://localhost:8000/` the running engine server.

I'm trying to create a query like this way:

```
curl -k -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{'intlPlan': True, 'voiceMailPlan': True, 'numVmailMsg': 41, 'totalDayMins': 173.1, 
    'totalDayCalls': 85, 'totalDayCharge': 29.43, 'totalEveMins': 203.9, 'totalEveCalls': 107, 
    'totalEveCharge': 17.33, 'totalNightMins': 122.2, 'totalNightCalls': 78, 'totalNightCharge': 14.02, 
    'totalIntlMins': 10.0, 'totalIntlCalls': 15, 'totalIntlCharge': 3.94, 'customerServiceCalls': 0}' https://localhost:8000/queries.json
```

It's throw an exception:

```
ERROR] [ServerActor] Query:
{intlPlan: True, voiceMailPlan: True, numVmailMsg: 41, totalDayMins: 173.1, 
    totalDayCalls: 85, totalDayCharge: 29.43, totalEveMins: 203.9, totalEveCalls: 107, 
    totalEveCharge: 17.33, totalNightMins: 122.2, totalNightCalls: 78, totalNightCharge: 14.02, 
    totalIntlMins: 10.0, totalIntlCalls: 15, totalIntlCharge: 3.94, customerServiceCalls: 0}

Stack Trace:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.org$apache$spark$SparkContext$$assertNotStopped(SparkContext.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.defaultParallelism(SparkContext.scala:2061)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.parallelize$default$2(SparkContext.scala:723)
    at Algorithm.predict(Algorithm.scala:56)
    at Algorithm.predict(Algorithm.scala:9)
    at io.prediction.controller.P2LAlgorithm.predictBase(P2LAlgorithm.scala:70)
    at io.prediction.workflow.ServerActor$$anonfun$24$$anonfun$25.apply(CreateServer.scala:536)
    at io.prediction.workflow.ServerActor$$anonfun$24$$anonfun$25.apply(CreateServer.scala:535)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
    at io.prediction.workflow.ServerActor$$anonfun$24.apply(CreateServer.scala:535)
    at io.prediction.workflow.ServerActor$$anonfun$24.apply(CreateServer.scala:513)
    at spray.routing.ApplyConverterInstances$$anon$22$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ApplyConverterInstances.scala:25)
    at spray.routing.ApplyConverterInstances$$anon$22$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ApplyConverterInstances.scala:24)
    at spray.routing.ConjunctionMagnet$$anon$1$$anon$2$$anonfun$happly$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Directive.scala:38)
    at spray.routing.ConjunctionMagnet$$anon$1$$anon$2$$anonfun$happly$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Directive.scala:37)
    at spray.routing.directives.BasicDirectives$$anon$1.happly(BasicDirectives.scala:26)
    at spray.routing.ConjunctionMagnet$$anon$1$$anon$2$$anonfun$happly$1.apply(Directive.scala:37)
    at spray.routing.ConjunctionMagnet$$anon$1$$anon$2$$anonfun$happly$1.apply(Directive.scala:36)
    at spray.routing.directives.BasicDirectives$$anon$2.happly(BasicDirectives.scala:79)
    at spray.routing.Directive$$anon$7$$anonfun$happly$4.apply(Directive.scala:86)
    at spray.routing.Directive$$anon$7$$anonfun$happly$4.apply(Directive.scala:86)
    at spray.routing.directives.BasicDirectives$$anon$3$$anonfun$happly$1.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:92)
    at spray.routing.directives.BasicDirectives$$anon$3$$anonfun$happly$1.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:92)
    at spray.routing.directives.ExecutionDirectives$$anonfun$detach$1$$anonfun$apply$7$$anonfun$apply$3.apply$mcV$sp(ExecutionDirectives.scala:89)
    at spray.routing.directives.ExecutionDirectives$$anonfun$detach$1$$anonfun$apply$7$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(ExecutionDirectives.scala:89)
    at spray.routing.directives.ExecutionDirectives$$anonfun$detach$1$$anonfun$apply$7$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(ExecutionDirectives.scala:89)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl$$anon$3.exec(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:107)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

Can anybody help me? what am i doing wrong?

Thank you!